# Changing only one value of a key in a dictionary that has multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a key with multiple values assigned. I would like to ask the user for input (*new_population*), and replace the old value (*current_population*) within the key. I would like the other value within the key (*num*) to remain unaffected.

```
current_population = 5 
num = 3
dict = {}
dict["key"] = [current_population, num]

new_population = input("What is the new population?")
```

Say (for example sake), the value of *new_population* is 10. My goal is a final output of:

```
{'key': [10, 3]}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you aware the dict is a built in object? don't use the variable name as dict just in case your modules/other parts of your code need that built in function

Comment: Yes, I do. In retrospect I should have used a different name, but I just figured this was the most obvious way to say it was a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict["key"][0] = new_population
```

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, what you actually have is a dictionary where each element is a list. It is not possible to have multiple elements with the same key, since that would create undefined behaviour (which element would be returned by a lookup?). If you do

```
current_population = 5 
num = 3
mydict = {}
mydict["key"] = [current_population, num]
elem = mydict["key"]
print elem
```

you will see that `elem` is actually the list [5,3]. So to get or set either value, you need to index into the list you get from indexing into the dictionary.

```
mydict["key"][0] = new_population
```

(like in the accepted answer).

If you don't want to keep track of which index is population and which is num, you could make a dictionary of dictionaries instead:

```
mydict = {}
mydict["key"] = {"pop": current_population, "num", num}
mydict["key"]["pop"] = new_population
```